# Not getting the correct results of an SQL query to be displayed in a grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a query which only retrieves the records of the `Description` Field of `Table 1` that do not match or contain the keywords  available in the `Keywords` Field in `Table 2`. So the ones that match should not appear in the GridView, rather only the ones that do not match. I am trying to display the results of the SQL Query in a GridView, however I am getting the ones that match, which is not my requirement.

I tried running the SQL Query in SQL Server and it works really fine. Even in my web app it works fine, but only if I specify explicitly the keyword after the `Like` Statement. But rather I want it to span all the `Keywords` in `Table2`. Here is my code.

```
conn.Open()
For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.GridView1.Rows

    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim Records1 As String = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT Description From DB.dbo.Table1 " +
                                 "WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * From [DB].dbo.Table2 WHERE " + 
                                 "Table1.Description LIKE '%' +TABLE2.Keywords + '%')", conn)

        DA.SelectCommand = cmd
        DA.Fill(dt)
        GridView3.DataSource = dt
        GridView3.DataBind()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        DA.Dispose()
        dt.Clear()
        dt.Dispose()
    Next
Next
```

`GridView1` has the data from Table1 (`The Description`)
`GridView2` has the data from Tabel2 (`The Keywords`) 
`GridView3` has the results of the query

However, as said before I am still getting the ones that match. Is there something wrong with the format of the query, something missing or written in an incorrect format? Any suggestions or thoughts would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you compared the query that gets sent to the server against the one you tried manually using Sql profiler?

Comment: The query in my web app works if I removed `'%' + @Grid + '%'` and replace it with `'%Orange%', `GridView3` will have all the results from `Table1` discarding the ones which have the word `Orange`. But with this `@Grid` it doesn't work

Comment: That's why I suggested using Sql Profiler to compare what is actually getting sent to the server.  Off hand, using the '%' + @Grid + '%' looks like you'll end up with a query like this '%' + Orange + '%'.  In other words it looks like the query will contain the extra apostrophes and plus signs.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway, so where can I find the SQL Profiler in SQL SERVER 2008 ?

Comment: I presume you're using Sql Server Management Studio.  In that case the profiler is located in the Tools menu.

Comment: Didn`t understand why cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is used? when the DataAdapter is doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't that be:

```
WHERE Table1.Description LIKE @Grid)"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grid", "%" + GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text.ToString() + "%")
```

Comment: still the same. Tried to many approaches still not able to figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Better solution would be to do this from within a stored procedure and pass the @Grid parameter. IMHO

But, to answer your question specifically, this should work

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim Records1 As String = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT Description From DB.dbo.Table1 " +
                             "WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * From [DB].dbo.Table2 WHERE " + 
                             "Table1.Description LIKE "
                             "'%" + GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text.ToString() + "%')", conn)
    DA.SelectCommand = cmd
    DA.Fill(dt)
    GridView3.DataSource = dt
    GridView3.DataBind()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    DA.Dispose()
    dt.Clear()
    dt.Dispose()
Next
```